# Unfinished system call reported by strace

Tags: linux, system-calls

I've checked the system calls being requested by this process and what I got from `strace` is an unfinished output:

**command**: `strace -s 99 -ffp [PID]`

**output**: `read(0,`

I've got the following questions:

1. Does this mean that my process is **stuck** in a system call (such as reported here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504841/simulating-a-process-stuck-in-a-blocking-system-call)?
2. **Why** does this happen?
3. Is it a **bug** in the program or in the kernel?
4. Is there any **fix** other than killing the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that the program is waiting for input on its standard input (file descriptor 0). It's not a bug, and you can "fix" it by providing some input.